# how can i control chrome tmp file on centos?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever i execute selenium for crawling with chromedriver, the tmp file is created and not deleted.

How can I fix this?

Is there any options that it deletes those files automatically? or control this?

version:

- centos7
- ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49
- selenium 4.8.2
- Google Chrome 112.0.5615.121
- python 3.7.16

```bash
[root@test1 tmp]$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 11 root     root     286 Apr 18 10:53 .
dr-xr-xr-x 20 root     root     279 Apr 17 15:21 ..
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:47 .com.google.Chrome.hEVvX9
drwx------  2 root root   6 Apr 18 10:52 .com.google.Chrome.HNG95a
drwx------  3 root root  83 Apr 18 10:52 .com.google.Chrome.IRMOi1
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:50 .com.google.Chrome.kG545m
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:49 .com.google.Chrome.NU3YYs
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:44 .com.google.Chrome.qvUUOt
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:52 .com.google.Chrome.u1wbFD
drwx------  3 root root  21 Apr 18 10:45 .com.google.Chrome.zCWoKU
drwx------  6 root root  88 Apr 18 10:40 Crashpad
```

Comment: You can use `cron` to delete it periodically.

Comment: no other way except `cron`? T.T